# How to disable "extra packages can be installed" popup in Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, flash, notification, ubuntu-restricted-extras

Kubuntu 15.04 shows a notification (and a taskbar icon) on each boot, after the log in, offering me to install extra packages, specifically flash, and I really don't want to install it. I've pressed "cancel" many times, but in the next boot the notification will pop-up again.

What can I do to make the notification stop?

Comment: you can remove `update-manager` package. your `apt-get` and `synaptic` will still work without any problems. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the entire update manger, thats a horrible idea!

Answer (score 20):

I found an answer to this [on the Kubuntu forum](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67909-Flash-notification-every-boot&p=370610&viewfull=1#post370610).

In KDE you can turn off "Restricted codec availability" under

'`System Settings`' -> `Notifications` -> '`Other Notifications`'.

It works for me (Kubuntu 15.04 with kubuntu-ppa backports).

Comment: @redanimalwar: my suggestion was to turn off "Restricted codec availability" notifications. This is not *all* other notifications. I do agree that not recommending flash in the first place would be better, though.

Comment: Nevermind I just read that totally wrong, I thought there is a checkbox for turning all other notifications off. Cant take my downvote away for whatever stupid reason stackoverflow has for this, sorry.