# Kubuntu 15.04 complaining about flash-plugin installer

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, kubuntu, flash

A few days ago I've upgraded from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 (yes, I've waited a long time before doing this...). Somehow since the upgrade Kubuntu has started reminding me that there's problem downloading the flash-plugin installer. I don't care about that because I use the pepperflash/freshplayer system and I don't need the flash-plugin installer which is outdated anyway so I've dismissed the message. However the message returns at each boot. I've dismissed it each time but it seems I can't get rid of it permanently. How do I solve this?

Comment: right-click on it -> Don't remind me again! (?)

Comment: Another option was suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/671663/472414

'System Settings' -> Notifications -> 'Other Notifications'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out be really simple. The package was in `/var/cache/apt/packages/partial`. I've deleted it there and the message has never returned.